# Loading Posts and Comments to User's Profile using AngularFire v0.8.0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase, angularfire

Referring to [Thinkster.io Tutorial](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/dVRdu6dXNT/8-adding-comments-and-voting-to-our-application), *( **Note**: As of now the tutorial works on AngularFire v0.7.0 and I am trying to update the code to AngularFire v0.8.0 )*

I am trying to load posts and comments which the currently logged in user has created.
Posts are loaded successfully but the comments are not.

Basically, firebase structure has two entities ----> posts and users

I am logging in from User A. Totally three users are created and only User A has made a post and commented on the same post.

Look for Firebase Forge structure bellow ( *You may skip this if you got the idea.* )

```
{
  "posts" : {
    "-JVSUl0lw7FI5CBKmxh0" : {
      "comments" : {
        "-JVSUnzHVuoh48LZ0jU_" : {
          "postId" : "-JVSUl0lw7FI5CBKmxh0",
          "text" : "First Comment!",
          "username" : "User A"
        }
      },
      "owner" : "User A",
      "title" : "First Post",
      "url" : "http://url-1.com"
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "User A" : {
      ".priority" : "simplelogin:72",
      "comments" : {
        "-JVSUnzHVuoh48LZ0jU_" : {
          "-JVSUqOA94On0xjmBnCT" : {
            "id" : "-JVSUnzHVuoh48LZ0jU_",
            "postId" : "-JVSUl0lw7FI5CBKmxh0"
          }
        }
      },
      "md5_hash" : "d10ca8d11301c2f4993ac2279ce4b930",
      "posts" : {
        "-JVSUl0lw7FI5CBKmxh0" : "-JVSUl0lw7FI5CBKmxh0"
      },
      "username" : "User A"
    },
    "User B" : {
      ".priority" : "simplelogin:73",
      "md5_hash" : "2076105f6efe7c11e285add95f514b9a",
      "username" : "User B"
    },
    "User C" : {
      ".priority" : "simplelogin:74",
      "md5_hash" : "a6d14de05d7b2c3cf4fae7ae14cfa7f3",
      "username" : "User C"
    }
  }
}
```

The code used to load the posts and comments made by User A into his profile is written in a controller named **profile.js**

*Comments are added in the code for clarity. Please ignore if comfortable otherwise.*

```
'use strict';

app.controller('ProfileCtrl',
  function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, $scope, $routeParams, Post, User) {
    $scope.user = User.findByUsername($routeParams.username);

    $scope.commentedPosts = {};

    $scope.user.$loaded( function () {
      populatePosts();
      populateComments();
    });

    function populatePosts () {
      $scope.posts = {};

      angular.forEach($scope.user.posts, function(postId) {
        console.log("The value for postId is: "+postId);    //Console: 'The value for postId is: -JVSUl0lw7FI5CBKmxh0'
        $scope.posts[postId] = Post.find(postId);
      });
    }

    function populateComments () {
      $scope.comments = {};
      var postsref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'posts');


      angular.forEach($scope.user.comments, function(comment) {
        console.log("comment.postId is : "+comment.postId);  // Console: 'comment.postId is : undefined'

        //Hard Coding postId works fine.
        //var post = Post.find("-JVSUl0lw7FI5CBKmxh0");
        var post = Post.find(comment.postId);       // See Error Log at the bottom or                  
                                                    // See commented code (hardcoded) which works without giving errors.

        post.$loaded().then(function() {

                  //Hard Coding postId and id (id is for comment Id)
                  //Using this line of code gets the Data correctly from the Firebase 0.8.0
                  //$scope.comments[comment.id] = $firebase(postsref.child("-JVSUl0lw7FI5CBKmxh0").child('comments').child("-JVSUnzHVuoh48LZ0jU_")).$asObject();

                  //$scope.comments[comment.id] = post.$child('comments').$child(comment.id);
                  //Bellow is the New code For Firebase 0.8.0 - as $child is now not supported in newer API

          $scope.comments[comment.id] = $firebase(postsref.child("comment.postId").child('comments').child(comment.id)).$asObject();

                  // Clueless on how to change the bellow line of code to work with Firebase 0.8.0 

          $scope.commentedPosts[comment.postId] = post;
        });
      });
    }
  });
```

**Supporting Service methods** called are coded bellow:

**User.findByUsername**

```
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
```

..

```
findByUsername: function(username){
  if(username){
    //return usersdiv.$getRecord(username);
    return $firebase(ref.child(username)).$asObject();
  }
},
```

**Post.find**

```
var postsref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'posts');
```

..

```
    find: function (postId) {
        console.log("find method: ");
        console.log("postId is: "+postId);

      return $firebase(postsref.child(postId)).$asObject();
    },
```

**Error Log at Console:**

```
Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"
at Error (native)
at Ia (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/firebase/firebase.js:14:283)
at D.E.H (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/firebase/firebase.js:146:216)
at Object.Post.find (http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/post.js:29:34)
at http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/profile.js:33:25
at Object.forEach (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:330:20)
at populateComments (http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/profile.js:28:15)
at http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/profile.js:11:7
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11319:81)
at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:11405:26
```

Comment: This looks like an asynchronous timing issue. Obviously the comment's post id isn't populated at the time you're trying to use it in .child(). It's going to be hard to be more specific with this fragmented example; it's difficult to put those components together to try and reproduce the error, so that we can come up with a solution.

Comment: I had read about this somewhere and i think the code above i.e. 

`$scope.user.$loaded( function () {
      populatePosts();
      populateComments();
    });`

ensures that first user is loaded and only then the object is used by calling `populatePosts();` and `populateComments();`

Comment: Correct, but populatePosts() and popluateComments() do not wait for the data to load completely. Posts.find() is creating a new asynchronous listener (not re-using the already loaded data). While it is true that the data it gets will be from the local cache, it still is done asynchronously, and can't be accessed until that record loads completely.

Comment: I agree to above fact and i tried commenting both Posts.find() statements. After that i used console to print values of postId and comment.postId. I got the following output: `The value for postId is: -JVSUl0lw7FI5CBKmxh0` and `comment.postId is : undefined`. I think there is some problem with the entry point of `angular.forEach($scope.user.comments, function(comment) {` statement in populateComments(); method. **populatePosts();** is working fine.